# Cannot submit a pull request in angular/angular

Tags: github, pull-request

I discovered a minor bug in Angular's code, opened an issue on GitHub ( https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19078 ) and now I am asked to submit a pull request but I'm not a "git pro" and however I try it doesn't work out.

What I did:

- I read the guidelines: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#-submitting-a-pull-request-pr
- signed Google's CLA.
- cloned the repo using: git clone https://github.com/angular/angular.git (was it necessary?)
- edited the buggy file. (but without having the files, this step wouldn't have been possible, right?)
- made my changes in a new git branch: *git checkout -b my-fix-branch master*
- commited my changes: *git commit -a*
- VIM opened, I put in a message, closed the editor.
- commit seemed to be successful because in the terminal I see: *[my-fix-branch 24f1f306e] docs typo fix 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)*
- tried to push it: *git push origin my-fix-branch*
- typed in my GitHub credentials.

And now I face the error message: *remote: Permission to angular/angular.git denied to swirlsky.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/angular/angular.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403*

First I should complete this, and only after that I should open a pull request on GitHub, otherwise how could they know what changes I made in the code, right? ...and for that, will this one be the appropriate page: https://github.com/angular/angular/compare/master...4.4.x ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fork angular using the fork button on the top right corner

You will have a new repo at `yourusername/angular`, work and push on it.

Then, you'll be able to submit a pull request

Comment: Thanks! It was easy, I could even accomplish the whole procedure on github.com, didn't have to play with the terminal locally.